# Proving that $f$ is inegrable over rectangular $R=R' \cup R''$, union of disjoint rectangulars iff it's integrable over $R'$ and $R''$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Prove that $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is inegrable over rectangular $R=R' \cup R''$, union of disjoint rectangulars iff it's integrable over $R'$ and $R''$.

My definition of "integrable": for any $\epsilon > 0$  there is a partition $p$ such that $U(f,p) - L(f,p) < \epsilon$.

I've been trying to prove it for lots of time. I tried proving the $\rightarrow$ direction by assuming $f$ isn't integrable at $R'$, but I wasn't able using it to my advantage.

You have my gratitude for any assistance you may provide!

Comment: What does "integrable" mean to you?

Comment: I tried using, that for every $\epsilon >0$, $f$ is integrable iff there is a partition $p$ s.t.: $U(f,p)-L(f,p)>\epsilon$

Comment: @Choko I'm assuming these are rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^n$ given the [tag:multivariable-calculus] tag, but you should really give more details in asking a question.

Comment: @Choko I edited your question.  Did I get everything right?

Comment: @Choko How do you define a partition of a non-rectangular region?